# Promotion Effectiveness and Efficiency by Years

Tags: sql-server

Create Derived Tables to calculate total sales (sales) and total discount (promotion_value) by year (years) and formulate the percentage of burn rate (burn_rate_percentage).

My answer is :

```
SELECT
    LEFT(order_date,4) AS years,
    SUM(sales) AS sales,
    SUM(discount_value) AS promotion_value,
    ROUND((promotion_value/sales)*100,2) AS burn_rate_percentage
FROM dqlab_sales_store
WHERE order_status = 'Order Finished'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

But, there is an error : Unknown column 'promotion_value' in 'field_list'

Please help

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` is not valid SQL Server syntax, and `Unknown column ...` is not an SQL Server error, please correct your tags. We cannot help you unless you give us the full table definition. Is there actually a `promotion_value` column in the table?

Comment: You cannot refer to an alias defined in the same scope. You must repeat the expression in your last column expression at a minimum.  And `LEFT(order_date,4) AS years` has a bad smell.

Comment: You should point out that this is a homework question. Also, the original data set that comes from DQLab is for MySQL, not Microsoft SQL Server.